Both Text and Image generation
I want to write a code in python using Ollama and llama 2 Large language model for text Generation using langchain api
and stable diffusion Model for Image generation from text . So i want help from your end that how it will possible that both text and image generation works together so that llms understand the question that it is a text to text question or text to image question

Please try to ask a question we can answer. We can't answer "I need help", but we can answer "I tried method xys, but it returns no image as expected".

If I understand you correctly, you want a model to which you give an instruction and depending on content of your instruction, the model will generate either text or image as a response.
The easiest option is that you can search for something like "generate image" in the instruction or other specific command which would trigger image generation. But this is probably not what you want.
Still relatively easy, but not optimal option is that you take a smaller model and give it instructions into its system prompt that it should recognize whether the user wants to generate text or image. You would need to give the message to this model first, then to your final one. This would, however, cause a large slowdown.
The best (but also most difficult) option I could think of is that you find/train a model which would do just one thing and that would be to recognize if user is asking for text or image. Then you would handle it in your Python script appropriately.
